# Minor Page Faults when writing to mmaped file buffer

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I'm noticing minor page faults when writing to a mmapped file buffer where the file is backed by disk.

My understanding of mmap is that for file mappings, the page cache has the file's data, and the page table will be updated to point to the file data in the page cache. This means that on the first write to the mmapped buffer, the page table will have to be updated to point to the page cache, and we may see minor page faults. However, as my benchmark below shows, even after pre-faulting the mmapped buffer, I still see minor page faults when doing random writes.

Note that these minor page faults only show up if I write to a random buffer (`buf` in the benchmark below) in-between writing to the mmapped buffer. Also note that these minor page faults do not seem to happen when using a tmpfs which is not disk backed.

So my question is why do we see these minor page faults when writing to a disk-backed file?

Here is the benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Command line parsing.
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: ./bench <path to file>" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string filepath = argv[1];
  
    // Open and truncate the file to be of size `FILE_LEN`.
    int fd = open(filepath.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0664);
    const size_t FILE_LEN = (1 << 26); // 64MiB
    if (fd < 0) {
        std::cout << "open failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd, FILE_LEN) < 0) {
        std::cout << "ftruncate failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // `mmap` the file and pre-fault it.
    char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(mmap(nullptr, FILE_LEN, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0));
    if(ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
       std::cout << "mmap failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
       exit(1);
    }
    memset(ptr, 'A', FILE_LEN);
  
    // Create a temporary buffer to clear the cache.
    constexpr size_t BUF_LEN = (1 << 22); // 4MiB
    char* buf = new char[BUF_LEN];
    memset(buf, 'B', BUF_LEN);

    std::cout << "Opened file " << fd << ", pre faulted " << ptr[rand() % FILE_LEN] << " " << buf[rand() % BUF_LEN]<< std::endl;
  
  
    // Run the actual benchmark
    rusage usage0, usage1;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &usage0);
    unsigned int x = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      char c = i % 26 + 'a';
      const size_t WRITE_SIZE = 1024;
      size_t start = i*WRITE_SIZE;
      if (start + WRITE_SIZE >= FILE_LEN) {
        start %= FILE_LEN;
      }
      memset(ptr + start, c, WRITE_SIZE);
      x += ptr[start];


      char d = (c * 142) % 26 + 'a';
      for (size_t k = 0; k < BUF_LEN; ++k) {
        buf[k] = d;
      }
      x += buf[int(d)];
    }
    std::cout << "Using the buffers " << ptr[rand() % FILE_LEN] << " " << buf[rand() % BUF_LEN] << " " << x << std::endl;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &usage1);

    std::cout << "========================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Minor page faults = " << usage1.ru_minflt - usage0.ru_minflt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========================" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running `./bench "/dev/shm/test.txt"` where /dev/shm/ uses the tmpfs filesystem, the benchmark always shows 0 minor page faults.
Running `./bench "/home/username/test.txt"`, the benchmark above shows ~200 minor page faults.
i.e. I see output like this with the above command:

```
========================
Minor page faults = 231
========================
```

Note that increasing the number of iterations in the benchmark correlates to an increase in number of minor page faults as well (e.g. changing number of iterations fromm 1000 to 2000 results in ~450 minor page faults).

Comment: Even after prefaulting, the kernel is still free to drop pages from cache at any time (writing back if they are dirty), requiring another fault if you access it again later.  You might also be faulting in pages of libc, etc.

Comment: Maybe you are not the only one using the cache so something else accessing somewhere else evicts your cached page? Maybe an antivirus does this?

Comment: @NateEldredge can you explain why a flushing a dirty page would cause the page table to be cleared? Wouldn't the page still be in the same location in memory and hence the page table is still correct?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik no other program should be accessing this file (I don't have an antivirus)

Comment: Well, the usual reason to flush a dirty page is so that the kernel can then safely drop the page from cache, and use that page of physical memory for something else.  That said, I would tend to expect that the subsequent fault when re-accessed would be a major fault, to get the data back off disk.  I suppose it's possible that the page was read back into page cache in between, due to readahead or something, so that only a minor fault is needed to connect it back into your process's memory map.